# SendGridApiClient get delivery response

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Just started working on email sending implementation using SendGridApiClient. Have this line that sends an email

```
dynamic response = await _sendGrid.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
```

Response can provide `StatusCode` `Accepted` and nothing more. Was wondering how can I check was email delivered or stuck ?

Comment: Just a remainder that Accepted is not a string but a HttpStatusCode. eg.: `response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SendGrid API is asynchronous because the length of time it takes to process delivery of the email is non-trivial and dependent on factors like the receiving server.

The best way to keep an eye on events like delivered, bounced, etc in real-time is to implement the Event Webhook.

Take a look at this answer: [Can my ASP.Net Code get confirmation from sendgrid that an email has been sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218563/can-my-asp-net-code-get-confirmation-from-sendgrid-that-an-email-has-been-sent/31248116#31248116)